# perl6 Function floor works differently with numbers and strings?

Tags: numeric, raku, floor

Quick question:

-1.9.floor gives you -1, while "-1.9".floor gives you -2. Is it supposed to be so? Seems a bit inconsistent to me.

```
> say -1.9.floor
-1
> say "-1.9".floor
-2
```

Documentation says "rounds it downwards to the nearest integer". Should both be -2?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems to be some operator precedence. Make the number a variable and use floor on the variable it looks ok.

```
my $i = -1.9;
say $i.floor; #-2
```

I your example it makes:
.9.floor ==> 0 and then -1.0 ==> -1

Comment: Thanks Valle Lukas !!!, (-1.9).floor gives you -2. Thanks. Looks like -1.9.floor is actually -(1.9.floor) and the negative sign has lower precedence than the dot. Thanks!